# How to handle multiple errors for same field in bootstrap4 validation

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do bootstrap 4 validation and using the documentation i wrote the following code.
Now for displaying errors the documentation mentioned "invalid-feedback" class which i used. However i want to use multiple error messages for specifying which type of error is thrown. In the below example i would like to show a different error on empty and different error on invalid pattern how can i accomplish that using bootstrap 4 validation. For the record i took out things that are unnecessary and does not matter for now.

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password*</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password"
            placeholder="Password" maxlength="someno" pattern="a pattern" required />
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a password.
          </div>
          </div>
     </form>


    <script>
            // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
            (function() {
              'use strict';
              window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                  }, false);
                });
              }, false);
            })();
        </script>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: no mate not with bootstrap 4

Comment: thanks anyway, buddy!

Comment: Since the JS provided in the Bootstrap docs is just a "starter Javascript," you'll likely have to add some logic to control the display of the custom messages. Here's an example that uses data attributes on the inputs to assign error messages & uses a jQuery validator plugin to show the messages: https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-validation-with-custom-error-message-by-using-jquery/. I imagine you could do something similar (replacing the jQuery with a JS switch statement, of course).